# Barra de progreso en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, progressbar

Colegas,

estoy enviando desde la vista al controlador una matriz de datos para guardar en base de datos, pero son un universo de 6000 registros y toma su tiempo en procesar,
para no confundir al usuario quiero mostrar una barra de progreso como la de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen es solo referencial el diseño no es mi preocupación, si no como poder mostrar una barra de progreso mientras los datos se estan guardando.

no coloco codigo ya que no se por donde empezar,

Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar realizando una petición Ajax a travez de jQuery. Te dejo un ejemplo funcional y abajo su explicación:

```js
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        tmp[i] = 'hue';
    }
    data[i] = tmp;
};
function doProgress(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
      console.log(percentComplete);
      $('.progress').attr({
          value: percentComplete * 100
      });
      if (percentComplete === 1) {
          $('.progress').addClass('hide');
      }
  }
}
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

```css
.progress {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.progress.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-center">jQuery: AJAX progress bar</h1>
<progress class="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

**Explicación:**

Lo primero simplemente es tener la data que se enviará. Para este ejemplo simplemente se llena un array con 100,000 registros de ejemplo.

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        tmp[i] = 'hue';
    }
    data[i] = tmp;
};
```

Una vez tengas la información que quieres enviar al servidor haría falta crear una función que nos permita saber el porcentaje de subida.

```
function doProgress(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
      console.log(percentComplete);
      $('.progress').attr({
          value: percentComplete * 100
      });
      if (percentComplete === 1) {
          $('.progress').addClass('hide');
      }
  }
}
```

- [`evt.lengthComputable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/lengthComputable): es un indicador booleano que indica si el recurso en cuestión por el ProgressEvent tiene una longitud que se puede calcular.
- [`evt.loaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/loaded): es un indicador numerico que representa la cantidad de trabajo ya realizado, es decir, lo que ya se ha subido o bajado de nuestro archivo.
- [`evt.total`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/total): es un indicador numero que representa la cantidad total de trabajo a realizar. Es decir, lo que sebe descargarse o subirse.
- `percentComplete`: La división de lo ya cargado o descargado sobre el total. Esta división nos arrojará un numero mayor o igual a 0 y menor o igual a 1.
- `percentComplete * 100`: Multiplicamos lo ya cargado o descargado por 100, de tal forma que el valor resultante sea mayor o igual a 0 y menor o igual a 100.
- `percentComplete === 1`: Si lo ya cargado es igual a 1 significa que ya se ha terminado de subir o bajar nuestra data.

Ahora solo resta crear nuestra petición ajax según lo queramos.

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

- `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);`: agregamos la función creada como listener para el progreso de la petición en la subida
- `xhr.addEventListener("progress", doProgress, false);`: agregamos la función creada como listener para el progreso de la petición

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Saludos!

**Fuente original** (*En ingles*): https://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/XdGjGd

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tengo un universo de 7.000 registros que debo guardar esto me servira de mucho! muchas gracias, lo probare