# barra de carga en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, progressbar

tengo un sistema desarrollado en laravel, en el cual se tienen que subir videos, por lo que necesito una barra de carga que indique el porcentaje de subida como la que aparece al momento de cargar un video en youtube.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el diseño no me importa mucho, ya eh probado con JavaScript y Bootstrap, pero no me funcionan, espero me puedan ayudar.

**vista**

```
  <form class="contact-form" data-wow-duration="2s" action="{{ route('videoc.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                    @csrf

                              <h5>Titulo del video</h5>

                              <input class="form-control form-control-user"  id="exampleLastName" name="titulo_video" type="text" maxlength="160" required> </input> <br>

                              <h5>Descripción del video</h5>

                              <textarea class="form-control form-control-user"  id="exampleLastName"  name="descripcion_video" type="text" maxlength="250" required ></textarea> <br>

                              <h5>Archivo de video</h5>

                             <input  accept="video/mp4" type="file" id="file" name="video" required="true" ></input>

<button type="submit" id="subir">Subir Video</button>
                            </form>
```

**controlador**

```
public function store(Request $request)

{

    $video                          = new VideosCurso();

    $video->titulo_video            = $request->input('titulo_video');

    $video->descripcion_video       = $request->input('descripcion_video');


    $file         = $request->file('video');

    $nombre_video = substr($file->getClientOriginalName(), -20);

    $name1        = time() . $nombre_video;

    $file->move(public_path() . '/videos/cursos/', $name1);

    $video->url_video = $name1;

    $video->save();


    alert()->success('Video subido', 'El video se ha subido correctamente');

    return redirect()->route('video.show');

}
```

Comment: Bueno... está todo por hacer... Te podríamos ayudar con tu código, pero ahí sólo hay un formulario html y un método del controlador y nada de una una barra de carga...  ¿Qué has intentado/investigado y cuál es el problema puntual que tuviste?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Barra de progreso en laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201550/barra-de-progreso-en-laravel)